# How to keep list view items?

Tags: flutter

List view recycled items and reload again. I need to keep item details. Is there any widget that can replace list view?

I tried column.

```dart
ListView(
  children: <Widget>[
    caption(context, "Services"),
    serviceItem(),
    ....
  ]
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution
Just use SingleChildScrollView and Column.

```dart
SingleChildScrollView(
  child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      ...
    ]
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for your requirements what you can do is use a column inside SingleChildScrollView.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Appbar"),),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
           children: <Widget>[
           caption(context, "Services"),
           serviceItem(),
           ...
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

By doing this, you will be able to replace your listview according to your requirements without building each your widgets every time.

Comment: Could you explain more on why this could maintain the `State`? I can't figure out If we call `setState`, the items still maintain states because we used `SingleChildScrollView` and `Column`. Thanks.